# Pass DataSet From WCF Service to Silverlight application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a DataSet of around 20,000 rows that I convert into an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` with this code:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> IEnu = ds.Tables[0]
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => ds.Tables[0]
        .Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => new {
            Column = c.ColumnName,
            Value = r[c]
        }).ToDictionary(
            i => i.Column,
            i => i.Value != DBNull.Value ? i.Value : null
        )
    );
```

but the `IENU` object size is much too large (around 7 to 8 MB). This is a very large size to pass thru the service. Another option is to generate XML of dataset (it's around  1 to 2 MB) but there is still a problem in that I don't recognize a datatype of XML node data, also I don't create any class which contain's property of XML node and create a list because my select query is criteria base so generate at client side after pass in sql

So how can I pass datatype in XML or is there any other way to pass data from WCF service to a Silverlight application?

Comment: Easy: **don't pass back 20'000 rows at once**! If you pass back your data in manageable chunks of e.g. 100 rows at a time, your size will be down to 40K ......

Comment: The other point I would like to make: you shouldn't create a dictionary with an "anonymous" object - that way, you'll never know what you're dealing with. Create a custom class e.g. `Customer` or `Person` or whatever you're dealing with, and then create a `IEnumerable<Customer>` or `IEnumerable<Person>` - that way, you get a list of **known object classes** - you **know** what you're dealing with.

Comment: Maybe look into OData? It's the first thing that comes up when you search Google for "Data from WCF to Silverlight".
MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838234(v=vs.95).aspx
OData site - http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols

Answer (score 2):

Services should return strongly typed objects that are serialized to an object or an array of objects into either SOAP, POX (plain old xml rest) or json (javascript object notation).  If you use REST, WCF can return XML or JSON format simply by attributing objects with DataContract attributes.

DataSets (or DataReaders) come back from databases.  Services provide an abstraction over the storage mechanism which may change over time.

By passing back serialized objects, the silverlight (or anyother client) can deserialize them into objects which are much easier to deal with.

Also, I second the comment about not passing back 20K rows.  Find ways to page your data (request in chunks).

Search for REST and WCF or Web Services and WCF.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an interesting post for you 
http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx